# laravel viewing table values instead of using $id to $ticket_id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I am trying to get data from two different tables example table A &
table B both tables having user_id & ticket_id column I am trying to
display if auth id and user_id are same along with Table A ticket_id
and Table B ticket_id are same then show or display data in view.blade.php,

I tried below code but it not working it showing error my URL is

> http://127.0.0.1:8004/ticket_chat/1560242956

if I modified instead of ticket_id to the table id number

http://127.0.0.1:8004/ticket_chat/1

it working.

the problem was I am not getting data by using ticket_id and I getting
data when I put id, I do not write any code by display data using
table id.

my controller

```
public function ticket_chat($ticket_id )
        {  
              $notification = Notification::where('status','ACTIVE')->get(); 
              $ticket_chat = Ticket::where('user_filter_id','=',Auth::id())->where('status','=','OPEN')->find($ticket_id );
              $message = Ticket_Chat::where('user_filter_id','=',Auth::id())->find($ticket_id );
              return view('User/ticket.ticket_chat',compact('notification','message','ticket_chat'));
        }
```

my route

```
Route::get('ticket_chat/{ticket_id }', 'TicketController@ticket_chat');
```

my view

```
@include('User/support/support_header')
 <div class="page-wrapper">
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <!-- Container fluid  -->
            <!-- ============================================================== -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- ============================================================== -->

                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card m-b-0">
                            <!-- .chat-row -->
                            
                                <!-- .chat-left-panel -->
                            
                                <!-- .chat-left-panel -->
                                <!-- .chat-right-panel -->
                                 <div class="chat-right-aside">
                                    <div class="chat-main-header">
                                        <div class="p-20 b-b">
                                            <h3 class="box-title"><u>Ticket Message</u></h3>
                                          
   
                                           <h4 class="text-uppercase"class=" box bg-light-primary">{{ $ticket_chat->subject }}</h4>
                                           <h4 class="text-uppercase "class="box-title">{{ $ticket_chat->ticket_id }}</h4>

                                          
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chat-rbox">
                                        <ul class="chat-list p-20">
                                            <!--chat Row -->
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="chat-img"><img src="1.jpg" alt="user" /></div>
                                                <div class="chat-content">
                                                    <h5>James Anderson</h5>
                                                    <div class="box bg-light-info">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & type setting industry.</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="chat-time">10:56 am</div>
                                            </li>
                                            <!--chat Row -->
                                       
                                            <!--chat Row -->
                                            <li class="reverse">
                                                <div class="chat-time">10:57 am</div>
                                                <div class="chat-content">
                                                    <h5>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h5>
                                                    <div class="box bg-light-inverse">{{ $message->message }}</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="chat-img"><img src="1.jpg" alt="user" /></div>
                                            </li>
                                            <!--chat Row -->
                                   
                                            <!--chat Row -->
                                  
                                            <!--chat Row -->
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body b-t">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-8">
                                                <textarea placeholder="Type your message here" class="form-control b-0"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-4 text-right">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- .chat-right-panel -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.chat-row -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
       @include('User/footer')
```

my error

> "Trying to get property 'subject' of non-object (View: C:\ticket\resources\views\User\ticket\ticket_chat.blade.php) ◀"
>
> "Trying to get property 'ticket_id' of non-object (View: C:\ticket\resources\views\User\ticket\ticket_chat.blade.php) ◀"
>
> "Trying to get property 'message' of non-object (View: C:\ticket\resources\views\User\ticket\ticket_chat.blade.php) ◀"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I thing your problem is that you are using "find" condition that automatically use the primary key column "id" of your model so if you want to use it you have to modify your model class and add the below line.

Ticket Model:

```
protected $primaryKey="ticket_id"; // default value is = id
```

With the above change maybe the below condition will works:

```
$ticket_chat = Ticket::where('user_filter_id','=',Auth::id())->where('status','=','OPEN')->find($ticket_id );
```

So if you don't want to change the primary key in your model you can try to modify your condition for this:

```
$ticket_chat = Ticket::where('user_filter_id','=',Auth::id())
                ->where('status','=','OPEN')
                ->where("ticket_id",$ticket_id )
                ->first();
```

I hope I've helped you

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Find method works only on Table's primary key only, default id is considered to be the primary key in most cases.

Change it to id from ticket_id Or Add below line to your Ticket Model

protected $primaryKey="ticket_id";